# How to calculate day between two dates?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

I have 2 textboxes, txtStartDate.Text and txtEndDate.Text, user choose date through calendar date picker. 
Now I want to count the days between the two selected date and save the result in the database field totalDay(type integer), the following is my code:

But when I click button and try to save it into database, i receive this error:

The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'time'.

What should I do to overcome this problem?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization

Partial Class addevent
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub ButtonAddEvent_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonAddEvent.Click

    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
    '"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eventdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)

    Dim cmdQuery As String = "INSERT INTO eventinfo(venue,totalDay,eventTitle,startDate,endDate,description) VALUES (@venue,@totalDay,@eventTitle,@startDate,@endDate,@description)"
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdQuery)
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventTitle", txtEventTitle.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@venue", txtEventLocation.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", txtStartDate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", txtEndDate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtEventDescription.Text)

    Dim fmt As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    Dim dtStart As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, fmt, Nothing)
    Dim dtEnd As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEndDate.Text, fmt, Nothing)

    Dim ts As TimeSpan = dtEnd - dtStart

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalDay", ts.TotalDays)


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    con.Close()

    Response.Redirect("~/addbooth.aspx")

End Sub
End Class
```

My table structure:
[image]

Comment: can you give the table structure of your table "eventinfo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your field is of type integer, and you only let users input days without a time component, the following could work:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalDay", ts.Days)
```

TimeSpan.TotalDays gives you days and fractions of days as a double, TimeSpan.Days only the whole days.

Comment: After I updated cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalDay", ts.Days)

I receive this error:

Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
The statement has been terminated. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
The statement has been terminated.

Source Error: 
Line 34:      
Line 35: 
Line 36:         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Line 37:         cmd.Parameters.Clear()
Line 38:         con.Close()

Comment: Was the code already working before adding the totalDay-parameter, or is this all completely new code?

Comment: before this i use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalDay", ts.TotalDays) i receive error The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'time'.

Comment: After modify to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalDay", ts.Days) appear the error Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant - I wanted to know if the saving of eventinfo was already working some day, and all the code concerning totalDay is new code. Because the new error-message could also mean that there now is a problem processing startDate and/or endDate. In the SQL-statement they come after totalDay, so problems with them could show up as soon as totalDay is working.

Comment: As you are parsing those dates anyway, you could move the setting of those two parameters further down and change it like this:

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", dtStart)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", dtEnd)

Comment: I just test, it cannot save startDate and endDate as datetime into database.
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Thank you! The problem had solve after replace cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", dtStart) cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", dtEnd)
and the count totalDay also working, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `SQL DataBase Type`  in the SQL Command Parameter list like below.

### Sample Code

`cmd.Parameters.Add("ParameterName", SqlDbType.Date).Value = "Value";`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Dim totalday As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, <Date_1> , <Date_2>)
```